# ssis expression

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a condition like this:

If col1 = ABAB Then Populate first 3 characters of col2 else Null

I have created an expression as below:

```
TRIM(col1== "ABAB"  ?  
    (DT_STR,3,1252)(SUBSTRING((DT_STR,10,1252)col2,1,3)): 
    ( NULL(DT_STR, 10, 1252))
```

However, it gives me an error.

Please help me on this.

Thanks

Comment: "an error". Care to say which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never closed the parentheses on the TRIM.  You might also have to cast the NULL as [this fellow determined](http://bobp1339.blogspot.com/2010/07/setting-null-value-in-ssis-derived.html).

Try this:

```
TRIM(col1) == "ABAB" ?  
    (DT_STR,3,1252)(SUBSTRING((DT_STR,10,1252)col2,1,3)): 
    ( (DT_STR, 10, 1252)NULL(DT_STR, 10, 1252))
```